# Breaking stylesheet caching dynamically with php based on last save date

Tags: php

Currently I have this in place to

```
<?php
$filename = 'catalog/view/theme/lexus_megashop/stylesheet/stylesheet.css'; 
//Save css to variable $filename
?>
```

Then in `head` I am linking in my stylesheet like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="catalog/view/theme/lexus_megashop/stylesheet/stylesheet.css?=v<?php echo date ("H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));?>">
```

This works well as it succesfully gets my last save date time and prints out `stylesheet.css?=v09:46:29."` What i am trying to do is convert this to increment in a version format

Say it starts at `?=v1.0.0` then when i save it will increment to say `?=v1.0.1` Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean that every client would have his 'versions' every time the page reloads(like you have now but an incremental number instead of a date) or you want set this version name from server?

Comment: Just from the server, unfortunatly right now I have to work on a live version of my site and i would rather it automatically add the version on server rather than me always having to change it myself. Basically i just want it to be in this sort of formatting ` ?=v1.0.0` instead of time format

Comment: Then, you need to persist this 'version name' somehow in your server (in a database, a file...). So you need a method to increment and store this 'version name' whenever you save a new version, and another one to get this 'version name' whenever you want use it.